# EC2 Kernel without rpcsec_gss_krb5 mod

Tags: kernel, nfs, amazon-ec2

I'm looking into setting up NFSv4 with kerberos (via [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto)). I believe I have everything working except I'm running kernel `3.0.0-16-virtual` which doesn't seem to include `rpcsec_gss_krb5`. Which causes this command `modprobe rpcsec_gss_krb5` to fail with `FATAL: Module rpcsec_gss_krb5 not found.`.

If I try to proceed mounting the NFS without this module.

```
# sudo mount -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5 *my ip*:/ /mnt
```

Stdout:

```
mount.nfs4: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

syslog

```
gss_create: Pseudoflavor 390003 not found!
RPC: Couldn't create auth handle (flavor 390003)
```

How should I ago about adding this mod to the EC2 Ubuntu kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running 10.10 (Oneiric) you should have access to the `linux-image-extra` package which contains all of the modules normally stripped from the primary `-virtual` kernel.  With this installed the `-virtual` kernel should have all of the same modules as a traditional `-server` kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by just apt-get'ing the kernel I wanted.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.0.0-17-server
sudo nano /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

Add above others in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.

```
title           Ubuntu 11.10, kernel 3.0.0-17-server
root            (hd0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-17-server root=LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs ro console=hvc0  crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-17-server
```

`sudo reboot`

Comment: The problem with adding this kernel manually is you will not receive any updates for it.  You should install linux-image-server which will pull in updates as they occur.  That said you probabally should be using linux-image-extras for this with the virtual kernels, see the other answer.